# Basic cuBLAS dot product of large arrays returns incorrect values

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, cuda, cublas

I have the following code written in cuda-C (Visual Studio 2015 on Win-10, GPU device = TitanXp) to calculate sum of all elements in a 1D-array (flattened from 2D). The host version is straightforward with the `+=` operation to sum all elements and return the value. for the cuBLAS implementation, I used the dot-product approach (perform dot product of the target array with an array of all 1's of same size, to return the sum of all elements). The code works for small arrays (e.g. 100-element array), however returns incorrect values (though close enough to the correct value) for large arrays (e.g. 512x512 = 262144-element array). What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks in advance. (Disclaimer - new cuBLAS user).

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "book.h"
#include <cublas_v2.h>

void creatematrix(float *out, int nx, int ny)
{
    float ctr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ny; ++j) {
            out[j * nx + i] = ctr/1E+5;
            ctr = ctr + 1;
        }
    }
}

float add_arr_val(float *im, int N)
{
    float tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        tmp += im[i];

    float out = tmp;
    return out;
}

__global__ void init_ones(float *d_in, int N)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (i < N)
    {
        d_in[i] = 1.0;
    }
}

void main()
{
    // Define matrix size (using flattened array for most operations)
    int nx = 512;       // row size
    int ny = 512;       // column size
    int N = nx * ny;    // total size of flattened array
    
    // CPU section ========================================
    float *M; M = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));    // create array pointer and allocate memory
    creatematrix(M, nx, ny);                            // create a test matrix of size nx * ny
    float cpu_out = add_arr_val(M, N);                  // CPU function

    // GPU and cuBLAS section ==============================
    float *d_M;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&d_M, N * sizeof(float)));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_M, M, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));    // copy original array M to device as d_M
        
    // create array of all ones, size N for dot product
    float *d_ones;
    cudaMalloc(&d_ones, N * sizeof(float));

    // Max potential blocksize
    int minGridSize, blockSize, gridSize;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&minGridSize, &blockSize, init_ones, 0, N);
    gridSize = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize; 
    init_ones << <gridSize, blockSize >> > (d_ones, N);     // kernel launch to generate array of all 1's
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    
    float blas_out;                                                         // output on host variable
    cublasHandle_t handle;  cublasCreate(&handle);                          // initialize CUBLAS context        
    cublasSdot(handle, N, d_M, 1, d_ones, 1, &blas_out);                    // Perform cublas single-precision dot product of (d_M . d_ones)
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();    
    
    //print output from cpu and gpu sections
    printf("native output = %lf\n", cpu_out);
    printf("cublas output = %lf\n", blas_out);

    cublasDestroy(handle);
    free(M);
    cudaFree(d_M);
    cudaFree(d_ones);
}
```

Output for array with 262144 elements (flattened 512x512 matrix):

```
native output = 343590.437500
cublas output = 343596.062500
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Output for array with 144 elements (flattened 12x12 matrix):

```
native output = 0.102960
cublas output = 0.102960
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 3):

You're running into the limits of `float` precision.  It really shouldn't be expected to have more than about 5 decimal digits of accuracy, and certain calculation patterns can cause it to have less accuracy than that.  In fact, *the CUBLAS result is numerically closer to the correctly rounded result than your CPU implementation is*.    This is easy to prove.  All we need to do is perform your host summing operation using `double`  and we see that we get a different result:

```
$ cat t1784.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#define HANDLE_ERROR(x) x
void creatematrix(float *out, int nx, int ny)
{
    float ctr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ny; ++j) {
            out[j * nx + i] = ctr/1E+5;
            ctr = ctr + 1;
        }
    }
}

float add_arr_val(float *im, int N)
{
    float tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        tmp += im[i];

    float out = tmp;
    return out;
}

double add_arr_val_dbl(float *im, int N)
{
    double tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        tmp += (double)(im[i]);

    return tmp;
}


__global__ void init_ones(float *d_in, int N)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (i < N)
    {
        d_in[i] = 1.0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Define matrix size (using flattened array for most operations)
    int nx = 512;       // row size
    int ny = 512;       // column size
    int N = nx * ny;    // total size of flattened array

    // CPU section ========================================
    float *M; M = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));    // create array pointer and allocate memory
    creatematrix(M, nx, ny);                            // create a test matrix of size nx * ny
    float cpu_out = add_arr_val(M, N);                  // CPU function
    double cpu_dbl_out = add_arr_val_dbl(M, N);
    // GPU and cuBLAS section ==============================
    float *d_M;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&d_M, N * sizeof(float)));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_M, M, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));    // copy original array M to device as d_M

    // create array of all ones, size N for dot product
    float *d_ones;
    cudaMalloc(&d_ones, N * sizeof(float));

    // Max potential blocksize
    int minGridSize, blockSize, gridSize;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&minGridSize, &blockSize, init_ones, 0, N);
    gridSize = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    init_ones << <gridSize, blockSize >> > (d_ones, N);     // kernel launch to generate array of all 1's
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    float blas_out;                                                         // output on host variable
    cublasHandle_t handle;  cublasCreate(&handle);                          // initialize CUBLAS context
    cublasSdot(handle, N, d_M, 1, d_ones, 1, &blas_out);                    // Perform cublas single-precision dot product of (d_M . d_ones)
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //print output from cpu and gpu sections
    printf("native output = %f\n", cpu_out);
    printf("native double output = %f\n", cpu_dbl_out);
    printf("cublas output = %f\n", blas_out);

    cublasDestroy(handle);
    free(M);
    cudaFree(d_M);
    cudaFree(d_ones);
}
$ nvcc -o t1784 t1784.cu -lcublas
$ ./t1784
native output        = 343590.437500
native double output = 343596.072960
cublas output        = 343596.062500
$
```

The reason the cublas output is actually closer(*) is because it is doing the additions in a different order than your host `float` code is.  It works in threadblocks, and sums partial sums together, before creating a final result.

As a side note, there is no need to use `l` with the `%f` printf format specifier.  It is already designed to hand both `double` and `float` formats, correctly.

For a detailed description of how the error arose in your summation, you may wish to read [this paper](https://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf) especially "Errors in Summation" starting on p238.

(*) However, you shouldn't assume that this is always the case, although I believe the partial sums method is generally more robust than the pure running sum method (that's just a personal opinion, not a matter that I have proven or that I wish to argue).  However in either case the error is data dependent.  We can construct a particular data sequence that will make the running sum method look very good, from an accuracy perspective.  To perform a large summation where the highest level of accuracy is important, you probably should use the highest precision available.  Beyond that, you may wish to read about Kahan summation in the paper linked above.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanation and the comparison of host code with double-precision. I will take a detailed look at Kahan summation and the paper you shared. On a side note, for a fair comparison between host code w/ double-precision and CUBLAS, I will probably have to switch to "cublasDdot".